# How to change canvas size in 2D Animator

Tags: animation, interface, camera, image, constraints

Is it possible to set specific pixel dimensions for the 2D Animator canvas Or even to change the canvas ratio? I want to create an image with the specific dimensions of, say, 273x400p.

Answer (score 1):

Pixel size depends on your render resolution and camera, not your canvas.

You can change canvas proportions in *Viewport Display > Canvas*
And you can also adjust the subdivisions.

[image]